# ActionBarSherlock top-left icon doesn't navigate up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock to implement ActionBar for both Pre/post versions of Android HoneyComb.
My problem is that when I tap top-left icon on Android version 4.0.4, it did not respond.
Here is what I have done till now:

1) In all style folders "values/styles.xml" , "values-v11/styles.xml" & "values-v14/styles.xml"; I have done the following

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActivityActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActivityActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="ActivityActionBarStyle" parent="ommaralrd_transparent_ActionBar">
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
    </style>
```

In any application activity (except Home activity since it should not have Up arrow), I have done the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_inner);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
.....rest of my code ...
}


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            /*app icon in action bar clicked; go home*/
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

            /* With this flag, if the activity you're starting already exists in the current task, 
             * then all activities on top of it are destroyed and it is brought to the front.
             * you should usually not create a new instance of the home activity. Otherwise, 
             * you might end up with a long stack of activities in the current task with multiple 
             * instances of the home activity.*/
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In the Manifest file, I make sure that I have applied the respective style to all activities (except main activity since it should not have Up arrow)

```
<activity
            android:name="com.andrid.example.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrid.example.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

So now when I test the application on Pre-HoneyComb version, the Up arrow is never shown which is correct since ABS can't respond at all if icon was tapped to navigate up.
But when I tried the application on Post-HoneyComb version like 4.1 on Emulator, the Up arrow is shown and when I tapped it, it works as expected and navigates up normally.
My problem is that when I tried the application on Android 4.0.4 emulator , the Up arrow is shown as expected but when I tapped it, it do nothing

Comment: On the contrary, using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` allows the home to be clicked on *all* versions, even 2.2. You even get the arrow.

Comment: @A--C You are correct about but what i have noted that the home icon is clickable for Android 4.1 and not clickable for Android 4.0 upon using Action Bar Sherlock......You can try this in two different emulators for 4.1 and 4.0 to reproduce my problem

Comment: I used the bare minimum, setting the Theme to `Theme.Sherlock` and using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` It works on ICS (4.0.4) properly, so unfortuntely I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @A--C I guess i found out the fix of my issue.... To reproduce the bug  exactly, Please dont call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled but instead use homeAsUp in respective styles.xml file. Simply I removed homeAsUp and used the explicit API setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled and it works as expected now on both Android 4.0 and Android 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix:
Simply I should avoid set the Icon Home as Up using xml attribute: homeAsUp but instead I should have used setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) explicitly as follows:

In all style folders "values/styles.xml" , "values-v11/styles.xml" & "values-v14/styles.xml"; I have done the following

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActivityActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActivityActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="ActivityActionBarStyle" parent="ommaralrd_transparent_ActionBar">
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
    </style>
```

in Each Activity (except main activity):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```